# how to remove a specific css from a div without adding an inline style?

Tags: javascript, jquery

clicking on the button I need to remove the following css setting from `#tg`:

```
.wrap div{
text-align:justify;
text-align-last:left;
}
```

and add a `acenter` class - i.e. making it aligned center

`#tgx`.should not be changed

I can do it by `$('#tg').css(...)` but it adds an inline style which I want to avoid

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
  $('#tg').addClass('acenter');
});
```

```css
.wrap div{
text-align:justify;
text-align-last:left;
}

.acenter{
  text-align:center;
  text-align-last:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='wrap'>
<div class='tg' id='tg'>lorem ipsum</div>
<div class='tgx' id='tgx'>dolor sit</div>
</div>
<button>CLICK</button>
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to dynamically add the `acenter` *css properties* to `.wrap div` css?   Are you saying you don't want to use `.addClass` either?

Comment: You don't need to *remove* the `text-align:justify` if you *add* `text-align:center` *after* as that's how css works - the last defined property takes priority.

Comment: Can you specify what your expected end result would be?

Comment: @freedomn-m - click on button should result in `#tg` - centered - without affecting `#tgx` and without using inline style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add for them a class. For example, I add for them class `oldClass`.
Then I can remove it by `$('#tg').removeClass('oldClass');`.

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('#tg').addClass('acenter');
});
```

```css
.wrap div {
  text-align: justify;
  text-align-last: left;
}

.acenter {
  text-align: center !important;
  text-align-last: center !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='wrap'>
  <div class='tg' id='tg'>lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class='tgx' id='tgx'>dolor sit</div>
</div>
<button>CLICK</button>
```

**Update:** I updated another solution by using `!important` to overwrite CSS because the author cannot add the HTML structure.

Comment: unfortunatelly I can't. starting scenario is - as is

Comment: @qadenza Could you change the CSS?

Comment: @qadenza I add another solution by add `!important` in `.acenter` CSS.

Comment: seems it works. I'm just afraid if there is any hidden downside of using `!important`

Comment: @qadenza just make sure the order of `.acenter` in loaded CSS is the last. It will be fine.